# Connect an existing postgres to express js using sequelize

Tags: postgresql, express, sequelize.js

I need to connect my existing database in PostgreSQL to my express js project with sequelize. what should I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can start reading the docs: https://sequelize.org/master/manual/getting-started.html

In there you have an example of a PostgreSQL connection